# About dict.fromkeys, key from filename, values inside file, using Regex

Tags: python, regex

Well, I'm  learning Python, so I'm working on a project that consists in passing some numbers of PDF files to xlsx and placing them in their corresponding columns, rows determined according to row heading.
The idea that came to me to carry it out is to convert the PDF files to txt and make a dictionary with the txt files, whose key is a part of the file name (because it contains a part of the row header) and the values be the numbers I need.
I have already managed to convert the txt files, now i'm dealing with the script to carry the dictionary. at the moment look like this:

```
import os
import re


p = re.compile(r'\w+\f+')
'''
I'm not entirely sure at the moment how the .compile of regular expressions works, but I know I'm missing something to indicate that what I want is immediately to the right, I'm also not sure if the keywords will be ignored, I just want take out the numbers
'''
m = p.match('Theese are the keywords' or 'That are immediately to the left' or 'The numbers I want')


def IsinDict(txtDir):
    ToData = ()
    if txtDir == "": txtDir = os.getcwd() + "\\"
    for txt in os.listdir(txtDir):
        ToKey = txt[9:21]
        if ToKey == (r"\w+"):
            Data = open(txt, "r")
            for string in Data:
                ToData += m.group()

        Diccionary = dict.fromkeys(ToKey, ToData)
    return Diccionary

txtDir = "Absolute/Path/OfTheText/Files"

IsinDict(txtDir)
```

Any contribution is welcome, thanks for your attention.